# Automatically Clean a target before building in XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, build

I try to automate my UI testing (using [FoneMonkey](http://www.gorillalogic.com/fonemonkey) ).
I have several targets, linked to different frameworks.
The issue is that I have to clean my targets before building them. If not, it looks like it loads unwanted frameworks (and thus has unexpected behavior).
So I'd like to know if there is a way to auto-clean the target(s) before building, by setting an option, using a run script...

I tried using

```
xcodebuild clean
```

But I get an

**ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DevToolsBase/DevToolsBase-1763/pbxcore/Target.subproj/PBXTarget.m:597**

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force the top level project to rebuild from scratch by removing the build directory. e.g. `rm -rf build`. This may be sufficient for your needs.

Otherwise, upgrade to the latest version of XCode, and failing that, submit a bug report.

Comment: Actually it would have worked, but I have a separate build path with all my builds, and a direct dependency which can not be built after the script that removes the build, so it is deleted after being built, and the file is missing. So I should have done rm -rf $(SYMROOT) but I found a better way : I set a separate build path for each target, so no conflict between them !

Comment: @Julien: good to see you have found a solution. You should write your comment up as an answer, then accept it :)

Comment: actually your answer is better for my question. My way doesn't clean the project before building it, and yours does. It would have worked if I didn't had a special structure.